# Add static route for SSH SOCKS on Debian

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, debian, proxy

I'm able to proxy requests via SSH SOCKS, when doing:

```
ssh -fqN -D 127.0.0.1:8080 MyUser@remote.ip

curl --proxy socks5h://127.0.0.1:8080 -d '{my: parameter}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://10.0.30.10
```

I would like to be able to just type:

```
curl -d '{my: parameter}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://10.0.30.10
```

As I also need to use the proxy in other applications where I cannot add --proxy socks5h://127.0.0.1:8080 (such as jQuery JavaScript http requests etc.).

Is it possible to add the proxy as a route or in iptables so I can use the proxy in other applications?

Answer (score 1):

The SOCKS protocol does not transport IP packets, only data streams, so a SOCKS proxy cannot be used as an IP router directly.

You would need additional software like [tunsocks](https://github.com/russdill/tunsocks) or [socks-tun](https://github.com/normanr/socks-tun) which does the necessary translation between SOCKS and TCP/IP.

Comment: I see, make sense. In the documentation it seems tunsocks uses openconnect?, can you give an example on how to use tunsocks in my case?

Comment: Ah, it looks like tunsocks is in fact the _opposite_ tool. Disregard that.